# Harmonic function in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

PROBLEM : Suppose that $C$ is a positive constant, $u$ is harmonic in the upper half plane $\Im(z)>0$, and that $0\le u(z) \le C\times \Im(z)$ for $\Im(z)\gt0$. Prove that there is a constant $c\in[0,C]$ such that $u(z)=c\times \Im(z)$ for $\Im(z)\gt 0$.

I made a new function $\tilde u:\mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ defined by $\tilde u(z)=u(z)$ if $\Im(z)\gt0$, $\tilde u(z)=0 $ if  $z$ is real, and $\tilde u(z)=-u(\overline z)$ if $\Im(z)<0$. I proved that $\tilde u$ is harmonic in $\mathbb C$, and made an entire function $f$ s.t. $\Im (f)=\tilde u$ and $f(0)=0$.

I tried to show that $\Re {f(z) \over z}$ is bounded to use Liouville's theorem to $e^{{f(z) \over z}}$, but I couldn't. (I guess it is not a good idea.)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you know the Poisson integral formula for disks, you can apply that to $\tilde{u}$ to see that $\tilde{u}$ is (real) linear.

Comment: Can you give me more hints? I know the Poisson integral formula, but I can't get that result by using it.

Comment: Differentiate under the integral, and use the estimate you have for $\lvert \tilde{u}(z)\rvert$ to deduce that the higher derivatives vanish identically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)